# git branch several commits ago?

Tags: git

Here's the current branch setup:

```
A---B---C-----------------D---E---F master
         \
          G---H---I---J---K---L branchA
```

I realized when I went to work on branchA, that the last few commits were for a new feature that should be a new branch. So I want to get it such that the tree looks like:

```
A---B---C-----------------D---E---F master
         \
          G---H---I------------M branchA
                   \
                    J---K---L branchB
```

I don't want to rename the branch, since that would rename G, H, and I to the new branch name. I can create a new branch, starting at I (`git branch branchB <SHA-of-I>`), but how best to "move" commits J, K, and L over? `git merge branchA` while on branchB just fast-forwards the branchB head to the same point as branchA.

Comment: What do you mean by "move commits JKL"? When you create branch B there, they are on branch B, as desired. All that's left to do is reset branchA back to I and do whatever it is that creates commit M (where did it come from?).

Comment: J, K, and L are the original erroneous commits that were added to branchA that need to be part of their own branch (branchB)

Comment: Exactly. But that doesn't mean they need to be moved anywhere. Unless there's anything on branchA, before JKL, that *shouldn't* be on branchB, just create branchB at the current position of branchA, then move branchA back to I.

Comment: Yes, there are commits on branchA before JKL (GH and I).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to move J, K, and L. You want them on branchB? Make branchB point to commit L.

```
git branch branchB branchA    # start branch B at commit L
git checkout branchA
git reset --hard <SHA1-of-I>

# If you don't want to check out branchA, you could use
#     git branch -f branchA <SHA1-of-I>
```

The thing that needs moving is *branchA*, which gets moved back to commit I.

If commit M has already been made, then you'll need to use rebase. Instead of resetting branchA, use `git rebase --onto <SHA1-of-I> <SHA1-of-L> branchA` to move everything past commit L on branchA onto commit I.

Comment: That's it! commit M is some new commit (that really should be on branchA), and the command I was missing was `git reset --hard`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [git rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your concern about G, H, I appearing on branchB instead of branchA. What I mean is, if you rename your `branchA` to `branchB`, and branch off from `I` to create the new `branchA`, and commit `M` to `branchA`, you should get what you want.

As far as I know, the branches are simply named heads pointing to particular commits (look at .git/refs/heads), and the rest of the tree is determined solely by parent-child relationships in git. Even if you somehow manage to rebase J-K-L onto a new branchB, and commit M to the now vacant space, the object data would be identical. Both M and J would point at I as their parents, and G/D would point to C as their parents, and the rest would simply point to their immediate parent. Am I missing something here?